# Change the font family and size in CKEditor 4.2 with class replacing solution

Tags: css, ckeditor

hello friends i need to change font family and size in FCKEditor 4.2 but i very search and i not found solution for this problem **in version 4.2** ckeditor.
At end of i found solution with replace css class .
put css class here for friend's that have similar problem and I hope helping them.

Thanks.

```
/*cke dialog label*/
.cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:11px;}

/*cke dialog title*/
.cke_dialog_title {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:12px;}

/*cke dialog tab*/
.cke_dialog_tab {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:11px;}

/*cke input:text*/
.cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content {font-family: Tahoma;  margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;}

/*cke dialog input text*/
.cke_dialog_ui_input_text { font-family: Tahoma; font-size:12px;}

.cke_dialog_ui_button {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:12px;}

/*cke dialog select*/
.cke_dialog_ui_input_select {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:11px; }
.cke_dialog_ui_input_select option {font-family: Tahoma; font-size:11px; margin-top:2px; }


/*cke ui button text*/
.cke_combo_text { font-family: Tahoma; font-size:11px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you're asking for. Could you precisely describe what you want to change/achieve?

Comment: You're right, because my English is so weak.
Do you have more information about CSS framework? CSS frameworks like jQuery?
This is the same way.
If you want to change the font family and size in ckeditor 4.2 , you have to act this way.
the main method for change the font family and size in this release does not work.
Do you know better way, please say ?

Comment: This code change ckeditor ui, font family and font size .
via CSS Class Replacing.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins

In config.js, for example changing to classes, add the following:
Display Name/Class

```
config.font_names = 
    'Arial/arial;' +
    'Comic Sans MS/comic_sans;' +
    'Courier New/courier_new;' +
    'Georgia/georgia;' +
    'Lucida Sans Unicode/lucida;' +
    'Tahoma/tahoma;' +
    'Times New Roman/times_new_roman;' +
    'Trebuchet MS/trebuchet;' +
    'Verdana/verdana';

config.font_style = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {'class': '#(family)'}
};
```

OR

```
config.font_names = 'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
    'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
    'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
    'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
    'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
```

Change the inline styles.

Comment: Only one downfall to using classes. It never replaces the previous class. What I am searching for and came across this post.

Comment: in new instance css class , you must using **"!important"**: for example :
`.cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label {font-family: Tahoma!important; font-size:11px!important; }`